# git merge de ramas error

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

he tenido un problema curioso para mi, al hacer merge entra 2 ramas

en la rama **uno** el fichero **a.py** tiene 90 lineas de código, 
luego se realiza el merge a la rama **dos** y el mismo fichero **a.py** que viene de la rama **uno**, ahora tiene 50 lineas de código,

ciertas partes del código no aparecen, no hay problemas de conflictos y ningún otro *(si se compila el py en la rama **dos** falla por que necesita el código que no esta).*

Luego se realizan cambios en la rama **uno** en el fichero **a.py** y ser vuelve a realizar el merge, 
los nuevos cambios si se mezclan pero los anteriores no

he borrado la cache de git, y hasta he clonado nuevamente el repositorio, pero sigue igual una parte de los los commits de la rama **uno** no pasan a la rama **dos**, (los nuevos si),

> La pregunta es, si existe un criterio especifico sobre los merge. o una cache especial de merge que almacene estos cambios y no los aplique

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema estaba en tener dos ramas y hacer un *merge* de una a otro, pero también trabajar sobre estas. En algún momento del tiempo una cantidad de *commits* de una rama se quedaron fuera de fecha entre una rama y la otra. Por ende, al hacer el *merge* estos *commits* no se cargaban.

no se si queda claro, porque es un problema mas de lógica, que de estructuras o código en si

Me contestaron en Stack Overflow, dejo aquí la traducción: [git does not merge the branches correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063080/1983854)

> La fusión no implica que un archivo siempre crecerá. Depende de la historia de ambas ramas ya que divergieron. Si en su último ancestro común ese archivo tenía el mismo contenido que en la rama uno, entonces en su rancho dos borró algunas líneas ... si se fusiona, el archivo permanecerá como en la rama dos, no se espera que crezca. Algo similar sucedería si eliminara líneas en ambas ramas (habiendo comenzado desde un archivo que tiene 100 líneas, por ejemplo. La rama uno borra diez líneas ... la rama dos elimina otro conjunto de unas 40 líneas, no las mismas líneas. Cuando fusionándote deberías terminar con un archivo de aproximadamente 50 líneas).

Comment: fedorqui, si editas la respuesta al menos, quita el [ en espera ]  de la pregunta